# How can i static link an external library using g++?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, opengl-3

I'm trying to build a program to test the use of an external library.
When I try to build it I get a bunch of "undefined reference" errors.

The exact line that I'm using to compile is:

```sh
g++ main.cpp -L"../Dependencies/GLFW" -lglfw3
```

And the errors are:

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:\Users\SubSm\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQmEHZX.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `_imp__glClear@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.text$mn+0xa): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.text$mn+0x45): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.text$mn+0x237): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0xa): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x41): undefined reference to `_imp____stdio_common_vsprintf'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x32b): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x3d0): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x405): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x44e): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x4d6): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x508): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x54e): more undefined references to `@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x3a): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x143): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0xa): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x98): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDIBSection@24'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0xc8): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0xdd): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateBitmap@20'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x100): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteObject@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x10f): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1b5): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteObject@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1fc): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x187): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x33c): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7a): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x8c): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x115): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x6b): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x49): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0xa): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x2b): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x3b): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x42): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x91): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x3b): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0xa): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x77): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x7f): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x87): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x13e): undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x6e0): undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x814): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x857): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
../Dependencies/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x6c): undefined reference to `_imp__SwapBuffers@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm trying to link the `GLFW` library

Comment: GLFW depends on one or more other libraries (looks like at least GDI).  You need to link to them as well.

Answer (score 2):

Manual says that you have to link to more then just `glfw3`

[GLFW: Building applications](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_link)

> ### With MinGW or Visual C++ on Windows
>
> The static version of the GLFW library is named `glfw3`. When using this version, it is also necessary to link with some libraries that GLFW uses.
>
> When using MinGW to link an application with the static version of GLFW, you must also explicitly link with `gdi32`. Other toolchains including MinGW-w64 include it in the set of default libraries along with other dependencies like `user32` and `kernel32`.
>
> The link library for the GLFW DLL is named `glfw3dll`. When compiling an application that uses the DLL version of GLFW, you need to define the [GLFW_DLL](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#GLFW_DLL) macro *before* any inclusion of the GLFW header. This can be done either with a compiler switch or by defining it in your source code.